# Running Android SDK Emulator Image in VirtualBox

Tags: android, virtualbox

Can i run the android image used by the SDK Emulator in Virtual Box ?

`Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86`

Answer (score 2):

You can us [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), which does that. Not sure if there's a way to do it manually without Genymotion. Obviously there's a way but not sure if it's practical.

Comment: I am not asking about an alternative, what i am asking is clear

Comment: Oh excuse me, I was trying to help you solve your problem. My mistake.

Comment: He was right you need both virtualbox and genymotion to do the job. It's not an alternative, it's the right way to do it thanks @JeffreyBlattman